# Can Google Cloud server as an endpoint for Snowflake HTTPS traffic?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm researching to see if it is possible to utilize Google Cloud as a proxy service, and if so, what APIs should I be researching? Specifically I need to determine if Snowflake can use Google Cloud as a https endpoint in order to pass JWTs to another service.

I'm new to snowflake and not sure what information might be needed to answer this question so please let me know if I should clarify further.

Comment: Stack overflow is oriented towards coding help rather than architectural help questions. Your question would be better if it were much more specific. Cloud Run is a rather generic compute service and so "can it proxy?" (yes, probably), "as a HTTPS endpoint?" (yes, probably), "to pass JWTs to another service?" (yes, probably) are all too generic for us to provide much by way of a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this blog post describing a Snowflake external function running on GCP Cloud Run:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/forecasts-in-snowflake-facebook-prophet-on-cloud-run-with-sql-71c6f7fdc4e3

In this example I configured GCP API Gateway as a proxy:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: API Gateway config for Snowflake external function.
  description: This configuration file connects the API Gateway resource to the remote service (Cloud Run).
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /test:
    post:
      summary: Prophetize
      operationId: prophetize
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://prophetize-zqnzinxyeq-wl.a.run.app/ 
        protocol: h2
      responses:
        '200':
          description: <DESCRIPTION>
          schema:
            type: string
```

On the Snowflake side you can set GCP API Gateway as a proxy like this:

```
create or replace api integration prophet_test
    api_provider = google_api_gateway
    google_audience = 'test1-xx.apigateway.x.cloud.goog'
    api_allowed_prefixes = ('https://xx-4r3ddv95.wl.gateway.dev')
    enabled = true;
```

In summary, yes you can.

Check their documentation for JWT authentication:

- https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt

If you have more specific questions while trying to make this work, please start new questions, and include all details to make them easy to reproduce and solve.

Comment: Thanks much. That seems like just what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Nyyen8 - if this answer is useful please accept it and upvote it